# How do I know which function is the upper function?

Tags: integration, volume

$y = x^3, y = 8, x = 0,$ we revolve around $x = 3$

The formula I have is: [image]

[image]

How can I know that its $8-x^3$ and not $x^3-8$ ?

Comment: Because $8$ is larger than $x^3$ on the interval provided.

Comment: The interval of $[0,2]$? Then $x^3=2^3=8$

Comment: $x^3$ is not equal to $8$ on said *interval*. Note that I meant 'larger or equal'.

Comment: I googled it and found a way to solve for average value of a function, but I'm not supposed to learn this. It's not something taught in class. Is there another way to see it?

Comment: So that we're on the same page: for all $x \in [0,2]$, we have $x^3 \leq 8$. Alternativley, you can recognize the shapes of the upper and lower functions to determine which is which.